# Google Cloud Platform system status page

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

Is there a system status page for Google Cloud Platform services? When experiencing issues where can we look for system status information?

For example, i changed the tier for a Google Cloud SQL instance and it went inaccessible for 12h. The next day the same operation took a couple of minutes as expected.

I found https://code.google.com/status/appengine but not for other products (e.g. Google Cloud SQL).

Comment: Unfortunately we do not have similar status page for Cloud SQL. As far as your instance is concerned; could you email the instance details to cloud-sql@google.com and we can take a look.

Comment: We now have a status page that includes Cloud SQL information. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is an experimental status page at [1] but actually is provided for test purposes only.

I suggest you to subscribe to Google Groups as they are updated with issues reports, Cloud SQL announce group is available at [2].

Regards
Paolo

Link:
[1] - https://status.cloud.google.com/
[2] - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-sql-announce/

Answer (score 2):

The [Cloud Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/) is the canonical resource for Google Cloud Platform service status, and it does provide information for Cloud SQL.